# Passing an object as subject to rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am running rspec tests on a `catalog` object from within a Ruby app, using `Rspec::Core::Runner::run`:

```
File.open('/tmp/catalog', 'w') do |out|
  YAML.dump(catalog, out)
end

...

unless RSpec::Core::Runner::run(spec_dirs, $stderr, out) == 0
  raise Puppet::Error, "Unit tests failed:\n#{out.string}"
end
```

(The full code can be found at https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-spec/blob/master/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/rest_spec.rb)

In order to pass the object I want to test, I dump it as YAML to a file (currently `/tmp/catalog`) and load it as subject in my tests:

```
describe 'notrun' do
  subject { YAML.load_file('/tmp/catalog') }
  it { should contain_package('ppet') }
end
```

Is there a way I could pass the `catalog` object as subject to my tests without dumping it to a file?

Comment: Do you want to use the catalog object across spec files ?

Comment: your link to full code doesn't work anymore. I'd like to see how you create the catalog object before dumping it into a file

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear as to what exactly you are trying to achieve but from my understanding I feel that using a before(:each) hook might be of use to you. You can define variables in this block that are available to all the stories in that scope.

Here is an example:

```
require "rspec/expectations"

class Thing
  def widgets
    @widgets ||= []
  end
end

describe Thing do
  before(:each) do
    @thing = Thing.new
  end

  describe "initialized in before(:each)" do
    it "has 0 widgets" do
      # @thing is available here
      @thing.should have(0).widgets
    end

    it "can get accept new widgets" do
      @thing.widgets << Object.new
    end

    it "does not share state across examples" do
      @thing.should have(0).widgets
    end
  end
end
```

You can find more details at:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before(:each)-block